# Ways to acquire the intrinsic lock for the thread calling the wait method

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait

Logically, it is understood that a thread calling the `wait` method should have already acquired the intrinsic lock of the object that `wait` is being called on.

It is stated in the oracle tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html), that "invoking `wait` inside a synchronized method of the object is a simple way to acquire the intrinsic lock", which implies that there may be at least another way to acquire the lock.

My question is, in order to invoke `wait`, is there other ways to acquire the intrinsic lock other than invoking `wait` inside the synchronized method? ... and what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few (closely-related) others that spring to mind:

- In a `synchronized` block:

  ```
  synchronized (this) {
    wait();
  }
  ```
- In a non-synchronized method, called from inside a sychronized method:

  ```
  synchronized void a() {
    b();
  }

  void b() {
    wait();
  }
  ```
- In a non-synchronized method, called from inside a sychronized block:

  ```
  synchronized (this) {
    b();
  }

  void b() {
    wait();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I am dying for one upvote ! ... would you be generous enough to grant me one?

Comment: I like your answer. It confirms that simple ideas could be the answer.